# Twilio is not able to send text message to DND activated mobile number

Tags: twilio

my client has registered to Twilio from US. I am developer and using Twilio service for testing purpose in India. I am sending text message to send One time password(OTP) to a mobile no in India for which DND is activated. I am not able to receive OPT via text message. Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid the DND list is the top limitation of Twilio in India right now. [You can check the details here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices).

You could, if you were interested, try using [Authy](https://www.authy.com/developers/) (a different Twilio service) to send OTPs to your users. If they have a smart phone, they can then install the [Authy application](https://www.authy.com/app/mobile/) and generate their OTPs on their devise without the need for an SMS. Check out the [Authy documentation](http://docs.authy.com/totp_getting_started.html) for how to get started.